# yum updates in fedora 17 going extremely slow

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I've just installed Fedora 17 and did an initial update:

```
yum update
```

yum update download speed is going way too slow.  Download speed is **5 kbps**.

Is there a way to tell yum to not pick such slow repositories?

Comment: This question is much better suited to superuser or serverfault.

Comment: noted, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: +1, my speeds are averaging 300 *Bytes* per second. Had no problem with yum in Fedora 15 (same datacenter, different virtual machine).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone wrote a yum plugin which addresses this very issue that tells yum to use the fastest mirror available, here is how you install it:

```
su
enter password
yum install yum-plugin-fastestmirror
```

Then I did the:

```
yum update
```

And now the yum update is utilizing the full bandwidth of my download speed.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what the problem was and I was considering reinstalling until I got it working. Glad I looked around first.